# c# asp.net jQuery AJAX Fetch Data From MySQL

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, webmethod

To explain what want to do. 
This (ver 1.) work fine...

Default.aspx (ver 1.)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#show").load("Data.aspx")
        }, 3000);
    });     
</script>     
<div id="show"></div>
```

Data.aspx (ver 1.)

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillList();  
}

[WebMethod]

public void FillList()
{
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name,Nick FROM dbBase ORDER BY id ASC"))
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use [WebMethod]....
NOT WORK

Default.aspx (ver 2.)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load()
            .$.ajax({
        url: "Data.aspx/FillList"
    }); 
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
<div id="show"></div>
```

And in Data.aspx I remove FillList(); from Page_Load.
Ajax don't wont call void FillList(). Can you see where is problem?

Comment: i am not sure how you are calling your web method. moreover WebMethods need to be static methods in webforms.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/08/28/creating-and-consuming-aspnet-ajax-page-methods.aspx).

Comment: Yes, as @GaganDeep said you need to declare FillList method as static to call it from ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your WebMethod needs to be static try...

```
[WebMethod]
public static void FillList()
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
[webmethod(true)]
public string FillList()
{
string str="";
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name,Nick FROM dbBase ORDER BY id ASC"))
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.fill(dt);
            }
        } 
      if(dt.row.count!=0 && dt!=null){
      return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
      }
      else{
      return "";
      }
    }
}
```